# unable to run sudo apt-get update

Tags: updates, update-manager, repository

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease [97.5 kB]      
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                          
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]        
Ign:2 https://download.rethinkdb.com/apt eoan InRelease                        
Err:6 https://download.rethinkdb.com/apt eoan Release                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 167.172.11.96 443]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: yes. thank you...problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

RethinkDB has changed their repository url.

It is now:

```
https://download.rethinkdb.com/repository/ubuntu-(insert version name here) (insert version name here) main
```

For Ubuntu Eoan, the url would be

```
https://download.rethinkdb.com/repository/ubuntu-eoan eoan main
```

Source: [RethinkDB](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/install/ubuntu/)